# Selecting data with counts more than 4 in a month from a daily data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to count the monthly number of merchants (and the total transaction amount they've processed) who have made at least 4 transactions each month in the last 2 years from a table containing daily transaction by merchants.

My query is as follow:

```
SELECT trx.month, COUNT(trx.merchants), SUM(trx.amount)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('month', transactions.payment_date) AS month,
    merchants,
    COUNT(DISTINCT payment_id) AS volume,
    SUM(transactions.payment_amount) AS amount
  FROM transactions
  WHERE transactions.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '2 years'
  GROUP BY 1, 2
) AS trx
WHERE trx.volume >= 4
```

My question is: will this query pull the right data? If so, is this the most efficient way of writing it or can I improve the performance of this query?

Comment: look up `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. Whereas `WHERE` works on individual records, `HAVING` applies filters based on summaries.

Comment: Can you add the table structure and some sample data? btw - the query, as it seems, won't work well in my opinion. without the additional info, I can't answer better...

Comment: The table contains date, merchant id, payment id, amounts, currency code (and a whole lot of other things). @GuyL - can you share why you think it won't work from your first glance? cheers!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Snowflake

Comment: As to your query: No, it isn't correct. To start with: it is syntactically invalid. For `trx.month` to appear in the result, you would have to group by it or not aggregate at all. Then there is nothing in your query to assure to only consider merchants that made at least four transactions every month in the last two years.

Comment: BTW: With most SQL questions it is advisable to show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I just read in above comments that your transaction records contain a currency code. Then be aware you must make sure to only to add up amounts of the same currency or to convert to one currency somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we must think about the time range. You say that you want at least four transactions each month in the last 24 months. But you certainly don't require this for, say, October 2018, when running the query on October 10, 2018. Neither do you want to only look at only the last twenty days of October 2016 then. We would want to look at the complete October 2016 till the complete September 2018.

Next we want to make sure that a merchant had at least four transactions each month. In other words: they had transactions each month and the minimum number of transactions per month was four. We can use window functions to run over monthly transactions to check this.

```
select merchants, month, volume, amount
from
(
  select
    merchants,
    date_trunc('month', payment_date) as month, 
    count(distinct payment_id) as volume,
    sum(payment_amount) as amount,
    count(*) over (partition by merchants) number_of_months,
    min(count(distinct payment_id)) over (partition by merchants) min_volume
  from transactions
  where date between date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '24 months'
                 and date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 days'
  group by merchants, date_trunc('month', payment_date)
) monthly
where number_of_months = 24
  and min_volume >= 4
order by merchants, month;
```

This gives you the list of merchants fulfilling the requirements with their monthly data. If you want the number of merchants instead, then aggregate. E.g.

```
select count(distinct merchants), sum(amount) as total
from (...) monthly
where number_of_months = 24 and min_volume >= 4;
```

or

```
select month, count(distinct merchants), sum(amount) as total
from (...) monthly
where number_of_months = 24 and min_volume >= 4
group by month
order by month;
```

Answer (score 0):

for get only the list of merchant you could use having for filter the result of the aggreated values  for distinct number of payement_id and month

```
SELECT merchants
FROM transactions
WHERE transactions.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '2 years'
GROUP BY merchants
having count(distinct DATE_TRUNC('month', transactions.payment_date))  =24
  and COUNT(DISTINCT payment_id) >= 4
```

And for you updated  question just a suggestion

You could join with the query that return the marchant with more then 4 volume for each month in tow year and   filter the result for aggreated directly in subquery  using having

```
    SELECT trx.month, COUNT(trx.merchants), SUM(trx.amount)

    FROM (

        SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', transactions.payment_date) AS month
            , merchants
            , COUNT(DISTINCT payment_id) AS volume
            , SUM(transactions.payment_amount) AS amount
        FROM transactions
        INNER JOIN (
         SELECT merchants
            FROM transactions
            WHERE transactions.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '2 years'
            GROUP BY merchants
            having count(distinct DATE_TRUNC('month', transactions.payment_date))  =24
            and COUNT(DISTINCT payment_id) >= 4
        ) A on A.merchant = transactions.merchant
        WHERE transactions.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '2 years'

        GROUP BY 1, 2
        HAVING volume >= 4
    ) AS trx
```

Comment: But this won't get me the monthly number of merchants will it? I want to extract the merchants by month if it is possible.

Comment: Your question tell "I am trying to extract the list of merchants (and the total transaction amount they've processed) who have made at least 4 transactions each month in the last 2 years"   .. the answer  retunr this list  ..   i can only read your question  .. and asnwer to this

Comment: ah my bad - let me reword the question. I need to count the monthly number of merchants who have made more than 4 transactions. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @KSoenandar  .. answer updated   hope is what you are lookinf for

Comment: Your `HAVING` clause only ensures there were at least four transactions in the two years, not per month.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  from the OP question  " at least 4 transactions each month in the last 2 years"

Comment: Yes, and `GROUP BY Merchants having COUNT(DISTINCT payment_id) >= 4` is asking for a at least 4 transactions for the whole time, not per month.